# Regular expression not working

Tags: regex

I want to extract from the following regex `(?<=^\d+\s*).*?\t` trying to extract from the following text just the resources\blahblah:
`10 _Resources\index.test   FAIL
11 _Resources\index.test    FAIL
12 Resources\index.test FAIL
13set\Relicensing Statement.test    FAIL`

but it captures the following text:
`0 _Resources\index.test

1 _Resources\index.test 
2 Resources\index.test

3set\Relicensing Statement.test`

I just want the lines like `Resources\index.test` and not the starting numbers, no spaces, why is failing? If I just execute `^\d+\s*`and matches with the any number of digits and space, but do not works with prefix.

Comment: Try [`(?m)(?<=^\d+\s*_?)[a-zA-Z]\S*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cd%2b%5cs*_%3f)%5ba-zA-Z%5d%5cS*&i=10+_Resources%5cindex.test+++FAIL%0d%0a11+_Resources%5cindex.test++++FAIL%0d%0a12+Resources%5cindex.test+FAIL%0d%0a13set%5cRelicensing+Statement.test++++FAIL&o=m) in Expresso, and [`^\d+\s*_?([a-zA-Z]\S*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%2b%5cs*_%3f(%5ba-zA-Z%5d%5cS*)&i=10+_Resources%5cindex.test+++FAIL%0d%0a11+_Resources%5cindex.test++++FAIL%0d%0a12+Resources%5cindex.test+FAIL%0d%0a13set%5cRelicensing+Statement.test++++FAIL&o=m) in Notepad++ (to replace with `$1`).

Comment: @Aaron: `\S` matches any whitespace. However, I do not understand this question to the extent as to post an answer.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, works perfectly, \S means non whitespace?

Comment: @jprz yes, it does, it's the negation of the `\s` space characters class

Answer (score 1):

Since you commented you were using Notepad++, how about matching `^\d+\s*([^\t]*).*$` and replacing by `\1` ?

Answer (score 0):

From [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/) (I saw it was tagged):

> Look-behind assertion. True if the parenthesized pattern matches text
>   preceding the current input position, with the last character of the
>   match being the input character just before the current position. Does
>   not alter the input position. **The length of possible strings matched
>   by the look-behind pattern must not be unbounded (no * or +
>   operators.)**

The same problem holds in most of the languages.

Can't you extract `$1` from `(?:^\d+\s*)(.*?\t)`?

Comment: He could use `?` and `{m,n}` which are bounded though. `(?<=\d{1,2}\s?).*?\t` should do the trick for example, or `(?<=\d{1,2}\s?)[^\t]*` to avoid the trailing tab. Of course, if he can extract groups it is most probably more efficient.

Comment: People tag their questions with nsregularexpression tag only because they think it is about regex, 99% do not know it has something to do with iOS programming.

Comment: When someone uses both [tag:nsregularexpression] and [tag:qregularexpression], it's a sure sign that neither tag applies; I removed them.

Comment: @Aaron Sure, it depends on how the user wants the regex to be generic.

Comment: @horcrux what do you mean generic? I was replying in the context of NSRegularExpression according to your quote. I agree variable-length lookarounds aren't supported by many regex flavours, but lookbehind aren't even supported by all regex flavours anyway, so I guess genericity isn't a concern

Comment: @Aaron "Generic" refers to the cases that may arise (e.g. more than one space, digit(s) not at the beginning of the line, etc.) that cannot be matched with a length-bounded lookbehind.

Comment: Oh, yes, then I totally agree.